# Will this R code count how many survey submissions had values for all 4 of these variables?

Tags: r

I'm teaching myself R and I think this code counts the number of times a survey has a value (not `NA`) for all 4 of these variables in `()`?

Can someone confirm or correct me? Thanks for helping out a nervous newbie. I need this number for a denominator (surveys without missing data). Thanks!

```
sum(!is.na(Both_hwstations) & 
    !is.na(Both_latrines) & 
    !is.na(rapid_unique$hf_ipcfocal) & 
    !is.na(rapid_unique$water_avail)
)
```

Comment: The value in the parentheses is 1 (TRUE) if all of those variables are not NA and 0 otherwise, and the sum is therefore the number of rows where all are not NA.  So I think you are correct, provided all of those four variables are vectors of the same length.  (If they are not all the same length, you will either get an error or the values will be recycled, but in either case it will not give you what you are looking for).

Comment: Hi Rair. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for posting. Your code should work, but only if all the vectors are the same length. `!is.na` will return a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and these should be coerced to `1` and `0` by calling `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think the answer to your question

> this code counts the number of times a survey has a value (not NA) for all 4 of these variables in ()?

is **yes**...  or rather yes, **but**..

Just to illustrate what everyone is commenting on:

This is a simpliefied version of the problem:

```
varA <- c(7:10)
varB <- c(1:3, NA)
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:4,
                 v2 = 11:14)
```

All, `varA`, `varB` and `df` have length of 4 or 4 rows respectively.

```
varA

[1]  7  8 9 10

varB

[1]  1  2  3 NA

df

  v1 v2
1  1 11
2  2 12
3  3 13
4  4 14
```

Your sum code

```
sum(!is.na(varA) & 
    !is.na(varB) & 
    !is.na(df$v1) & 
    !is.na(df$v2))
```

Returns:

```
[1] 3
```

Because it uses `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0` when trying to do math with booleans. So far so good...

But if we change the vectors to

```
varA <- c(NA, 0)
varB <- c(1)

varA

[1]  NA 0

varB

[1]  1
```

What would the expected result of the sum code be in this case? One row with not `NA`? The result of the sum code depends now on the somewhat idiosyncratic way R handles this situation where vectors have different lengths:

```
sum(!is.na(varA) & 
      !is.na(varB) & 
      !is.na(df$v1) & 
      !is.na(df$v2))
```

Returns:

```
[1] 2
```

Because R (in the background) doubled `varA` to make it the same length as `df$v1`. And `varB` was repeated four times for that matter...

For that and other reasons its often safer to explicitly bind the columns together first, and then use something like `complete.cases` to test for this things. That way we can be sure(er) that we don't accidentally mistake artefacts of the programming language as data ;)

We could instead do:

```
df$varA <- varA
df$varB <- varB
df

  v1 v2 varA varB
1  1 11    7    1
2  2 12    8    2
3  3 13    9    3
4  4 14   10   NA
```

And use base `R`s `complete.cases` :

```
df[complete.cases(df), ]


  v1 v2 varA varB
1  1 11    7    1
2  2 12    8    2
3  3 13    9    3
```

Comment: But hwy R is always making such things in the background? ;)

Comment: It only wants to help us ;)